# Извлечение блоков текста (регулярное выражение ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu

sed ubuntu регулярное выражение
Текст:

- dic_888_FL25_SH_2017-11-06_TFETJ_14_hands.zip
- dic_888_NL1000_SH_2017-11-06_RMKTE_17_hands.zip
- dic_888_NL100_FR_2017-11-06_JAZPS_159_hands.zip

как получить последовательно блоки заключенные в `_?_` построчно и записать так

- 2017-11-06_888_FL25_SH_TFETJ_14
- 2017-11-06_888_NL1000_SH_RMKTE_17
- 2017-11-06_888_NL100_FR_159

Comment: На питоне в 10 строк можно уложиться и без regexp. Осталось понять по какому правилу из третей строки исчезла часть "JAZPS"

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, неужели python столь многословен? на shell тут хватит однострочника: `cat файл | while IFS=_ read a b c d e f g h; do echo "${e}_${b}_${c}_${d}_${f}_${g}"; done`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin чтобы код был понятен - нужно писать больше. Открытие файлов, закрытие, вот это вот все :-)

Answer (score 0):

приведу пример с перестановкой местами трёх компонентов, разделённых символом `_`:

```
$ echo dic_888_fl25 | sed 's/^\([^_]\+\)_\([^_]\+\)_\([^_]\+\)/\3_\2_\1/'
fl25_888_dic
```

пояснения:

- `s/что меняем/на что меняем/` — наиболее часто применяемая команда программы *sed*, в первом аргументе команды пишем `что меняем`, во втором — `на что меняем`. аргументы могут быть разделены не только символом `/`, но и любым другим удобным. главное, чтобы это был один и тот же символ и чтобы он не встречался в тексте аргументов (например, запятая: `s,что,на что,` и т.д. и т.п.)
- `[^_]` — любой один символ, кроме `_`
- `x\+` — один и более символов `x`
- `\(выражение\)` — объявление группы, содержащей `выражение`
- `\1` — (только во втором аргументе команды `s`) подстановка значения первой группы (группы нумеруются слева направо)

---

подробности смотрите в документации к программе *sed*.

---

то же самое гораздо нагляднее будет выполнить с помощью posix-совместимой оболочки:

```
$ echo dic_888_fl25 | while IFS=_ read a b c; do echo "${c}_${b}_${a}"; done
fl25_888_dic
```